# Microsoft Word 2010 Compare Versions

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have one document that is the most recent/updated version of this document. Then in a separate area I have around 30 pieces of the document that need to be updated with the correct versions of word/charts/etc. Using the compare versions in 2010 it is hard to see what section to actually compare as it thinks that there is A LOT that has been added. Is there a way to section off the compare? Any thoughts/ideas would be wonderful. I don't have the time necessary to split the document into 30 pieces just to then individually compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

Here you'll find a step-by-step procedure: [www.codejacked.com](http://www.codejacked.com/comparing-two-versions-of-a-word-document/)